# when I migrate to AndroidX I got an error in firebase map fragment

Tags: android

When I migrate to androidx the firebasemap I got an error and I am using the latest version of google map view please anyone gives solution

I tried any solution nothing is work for me only I got this error error:

> incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

```java
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

```xml
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.xxx.booking.app.ui.Hotel.HotelMapsMarker" 
/>
```

please any give the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't import the androidX fragment, just use the normal fragment element.
Also, instead of using "android:name" use "class=" annotation in layout file as shown in the below code.

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 tools:context="com.xxx.booking.app.ui.Hotel.HotelMapsMarker" />
```

Comment: I need solution for androidx because I update the target version to 28

Comment: android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true


Add this two above line in your gradle.properties.
Then update your build.gradle dependencies as shown below:

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

Comment: Also, Don't forget to "Invalidate Caches and Restart" after doing above code.